# Recharts bar chart with vertical and horizontal bars (on each axis) - possible?

Tags: javascript, recharts

Is it possible to create a bar chart that has horizontal bars starting on the left and vertical bars starting on the bottom?  So two different sets of bar charts going perpendicular to each other on the same chart?

(I'm also trying to put a scatter plot in the background of the same chart!)

Thanks for any directional feedback.